# HTML + Javascript: can't get all instances from two elements at once?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, dom

I want to add a CSS styling class to all instances of a selective set of elements: for example, all **p** elements as well as all **h4** elements.

I define two JS variables which get all elements of the aforementioned tags, and insert them into an array, so that I can make a function which, in theory, should apply the selected class to all instances of the selected elements/tags.

However, when I run the code, it seems that the function assigns the class only to the first item of the array.

[image: Code and test]

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <style>
      .italic { font-style: italic; }
    </style>
  </head>
    <body>
      <h4>Text goes in here</h4>
      <p>Text goes in here</p>

      <script>
        function styleTxt() {
          let h4Elems = document.getElementsByTagName("H4");
          let pElems = document.getElementsByTagName("P");
          const elemArray = [pElems, h4Elems];

          for (eachElem in elemArray) {
            let elemInsts = elemArray[eachElem];
            for (eachInst in elemInsts) {
              let givenInst = elemInsts[eachInst];
              givenInst.classList.add("italic");
            }
          }
        }
        styleTxt();
      </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

If I invert the order of the element tags inside the array, then the **h4** element will get the *.italic* class but the **p** element will not.

Perhaps it is not possible to use the "document" directive twice? Is there an alternative method to automatically add the same class to a set of multiple (but not all) html tags?

Comment: You should check your browser console for errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looping through each property of the HTMLCollection, including properties like `length`, causing `givenInst` to be a number. Since it has no `classList` property, calling `add` on `undefined` creates an error and terminates the loop.

To solve this, you can use `isNaN` to check whether the property is a number or not:

```css
.italic {
  font-style: italics;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    .italic {
      font-style: italic;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h4>Text goes in here</h4>
  <p>Text goes in here</p>

  <script>
    function styleTxt() {
      let h4Elems = document.getElementsByTagName("H4");
      let pElems = document.getElementsByTagName("P");
      const elemArray = [pElems, h4Elems];

      for (eachElem in elemArray) {
        let elemInsts = elemArray[eachElem];
        for (eachInst in elemInsts) {
          if (!isNaN(eachInst)) {
            let givenInst = elemInsts[eachInst];
            givenInst.classList.add("italic");
          }
        }
      }
    }
    styleTxt();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

However,  a better way is to use a `for...of` loop instead:

```css
.italic {
  font-style: italics;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    .italic {
      font-style: italic;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h4>Text goes in here</h4>
  <p>Text goes in here</p>

  <script>
    function styleTxt() {
      let h4Elems = document.getElementsByTagName("H4");
      let pElems = document.getElementsByTagName("P");
      const elemArray = [pElems, h4Elems];

      for (eachElem of elemArray) {
        for (eachInst of eachElem) {
          eachInst.classList.add("italic");
        }
      }
    }
    styleTxt();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your second alternative worked perfectly for me! I should get to know more about the difference between for...in and for...of loops; perhaps for...of loops are the future.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to prefer the [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop for this and make use of the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). It will produce a much nicer code output:

```js
function styleTxt() {
    const h4Elems = document.getElementsByTagName("H4");
    const pElems = document.getElementsByTagName("P");
    const elemArray = [...pElems, ...h4Elems];
    for (const eachElem of elemArray) {
        eachElem.classList.add("italic");
    }
}
```

Of course, you can always pick both types of elements in one go with the `querySelectorAll` method:

```js
const all = document.querySelectorAll("h4, p");

// Using the for...of loop:
for ( const el of all ){
  el.classList.add("italic");
}

// Using the `forEach` method:
all.forEach( el => el.classList.add("italic") )
```

Comment: Thank you for both of your methods. I aspire to be a web developer, however I'm still at the amateur level and thus not familiar with lambda expressions yet. Anyway, I got to know the for...of loop and the spread operator, which were unbeknownst to me. Eucharisto!

Comment: In that case, I'll better refactor my code to include best practices: using const whenever the variables' values are not changing. Добро пожаловать! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Document.querySelectorAll()` to get both types of elements. Iterate the `NodeList` with `NodeList.forEach()`, and add the class to each element.

```js
function styleTxt() {
  document.querySelectorAll('h4, p')
    .forEach(el => el.classList.add('italic'));
}

styleTxt();
```

```css
.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<h4>Text goes in here</h4>
<p>Text goes in here</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try instead

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    .italic {
      font-style: italic;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h4>Text goes in here</h4>
  <p>Text goes in here</p>

  <script>
    function styleTxt() {
      const h4Elems = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("H4"));
      const pElems = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("P"));
      const elemArray = [...pElems, ...h4Elems];

      elemArray.forEach(eachElem => {
        eachElem.classList.add("italic");
      })
    }

    styleTxt();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```